# Changing a select statement to return all rows under certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a `select option` where the user can choose country and state.

The user can select an "all states" option:

```
<select>state</select>

    search all value=''
    CA value='CA'
    NY value='NY'
```

The query:

```
WHERE country=:country && state=:state
```

What value should I given if I want to search all state='' <-- search all

Comment: thats neither valid php or html, really no idea what your asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks guys, i have find a solution

```
if(isset($_GET['state']) && $_GET['state']!=""){
    $state=$_GET['state'];
    $state_statement=" && state=:state";

}else{
    $state_statement="";
}

WHERE country=:country".$state_statement." &&";


if(isset($_GET['state']) && $_GET['state']!=""){$SQL->bindValue(':state', $state, PDO::PARAM_STR);}
```

so if user not select or select all - value=""; the statement will not insert into SQL statement

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you would typically do something like:

```
WHERE (:country is null or country=:country) and
      (:state is null or state=:state)
```

Comment: so what value should i put inside of <option>search all</option>

Comment: Well, you can use any value you want.  If it is `''`, then you would say `:country = '' . . .` or you could use `'all'` or something else.

Comment: so $_GET['search_all']=""; -->$state=NULL; ?

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate "search all" functionality either rewrite your query not to include the filter, or substitute `value=value` (always true) SQL.

Otherwise you can inject your own SQL and have a conditional WHERE clause.

```
" ... WHERE 
        CASE WHEN '$state'='all' THEN TRUE
             ELSE state='$state'
             END
  ... "
```